# How to get the value of transmission(Tx) power of device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want the value of the transmission power of device. Is there any method to get it?

Comment: this might help you http://www.rapidsnail.com/Developer/topic/2012/39/27/50133/android-devices-how-to-get-the-ap-transmission-power-wifi-noise-intensity-the-biggest-parameters-such-as-code-rate.aspx

Comment: Have you found a way to get TX power of an Android device?

Answer (score 0):

For any given existing Bluetooth ACL connection, there is an HCI command to read the transmission power level.

Bluetooth Core Specification, 4.0, [Vol 2], Part E, 7.3.35, HCI_Read_Transmit_Power_Level

How this is serviced by any particular Bluetooth stack implementation, such as for Android, is another question.

Comment: Hi Pev, thanks for the reply. In Android, how we can get Transmission power of device? Please guide me.

Comment: Like I said, that's down to the Android BT stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the transmission power of a device in your Android application with a scan callback.  Note that for this to work you must grant the following permissions in your manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I've created a gist for an activity that obtains the transmission power of the sensor result from a BLE here:

https://gist.github.com/jamesjmtaylor/77578aaed78ee02f475bbbbc85f88e65

You can read more about Android interaction with BLE here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#HDP